# how to break down json response into multiple parts specific to the name value?

Tags: python, json, jsonresponse

hi i am making an api call to myfxbook api and in return i am receiving a json response with too much data , is it possible to break down the big response to multiple smaller parts with respect to what the name value is ?
Here is about 30% of the Json response:

```
[{'name': 'EURUSD', 'shortPercentage': 32, 'longPercentage': 68, 'shortVolume': 22685.66, 'longVolume': 47762.79, 'longPositions': 89968, 'shortPositions': 56612, 'totalPositions': 146580, 'avgShortPrice': 1.1678, 'avgLongPrice': 1.199}, {'name': 'GBPUSD', 'shortPercentage': 54, 'longPercentage': 46, 'shortVolume': 6462.95, 'longVolume': 5587.2, 'longPositions': 17783, 'shortPositions': 22240, 'totalPositions': 40023, 'avgShortPrice': 1.3592, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3929}, {'name': 'USDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 89, 'longPercentage': 11, 'shortVolume': 32447.66, 'longVolume': 4081.71, 'longPositions': 10941, 'shortPositions': 58722, 'totalPositions': 69663, 'avgShortPrice': 106.7526, 'avgLongPrice': 108.6437}, {'name': 'GBPJPY', 'shortPercentage': 79, 'longPercentage': 21, 'shortVolume': 2725.22, 'longVolume': 711.99, 'longPositions': 3210, 'shortPositions': 9743, 'totalPositions': 12953, 'avgShortPrice': 146.1479, 'avgLongPrice': 149.2243}, {'name': 'USDCAD', 'shortPercentage': 47, 'longPercentage': 53, 'shortVolume': 6235.58, 'longVolume': 6930.97, 'longPositions': 16121, 'shortPositions': 13276, 'totalPositions': 29397, 'avgShortPrice': 1.2658, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3025}, {'name': 'EURAUD', 'shortPercentage': 32, 'longPercentage': 68, 'shortVolume': 562.13, 'longVolume': 1170.82, 'longPositions': 4444, 'shortPositions': 3004, 'totalPositions': 7448, 'avgShortPrice': 1.5434, 'avgLongPrice': 1.5816}, {'name': 'EURJPY', 'shortPercentage': 74, 'longPercentage': 26, 'shortVolume': 10500.41, 'longVolume': 3672.26, 'longPositions': 8166, 'shortPositions': 25254, 'totalPositions': 33420, 'avgShortPrice': 126.1881, 'avgLongPrice': 128.6925}, {'name': 'AUDCAD', 'shortPercentage': 48, 'longPercentage': 52, 'shortVolume': 1559.83, 'longVolume': 1699.36, 'longPositions': 5943, 'shortPositions': 6278, 'totalPositions': 12221, 'avgShortPrice': 0.9561, 'avgLongPrice': 0.979}, {'name': 'AUDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 83, 'longPercentage': 17, 'shortVolume': 1614.66, 'longVolume': 322.98, 'longPositions': 1905, 'shortPositions': 6048, 'totalPositions': 7953, 'avgShortPrice': 78.9751, 'avgLongPrice': 83.5306}, {'name': 'AUDNZD', 'shortPercentage': 63, 'longPercentage': 37, 'shortVolume': 673.48, 'longVolume': 403.95, 'longPositions': 2123, 'shortPositions': 3785, 'totalPositions': 5908, 'avgShortPrice': 1.0644, 'avgLongPrice': 1.0779}]
```

as you can see the 'name': 'EURUSD' has multiple values like shortpercentage and longpercerntage , shortvolume and long volume etc etc

i am trying to get these shortpercentage and longpercentage for specific currencies and not all ,

like this :

```
EURUSD    32    68

GBPUSD    54    46

USDJPY    .......
:
:
:
```

i hope my question makes sense i tried my best to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use comprehensation:

```
# data = this is an input big data
interested = ['EURUSD', 'GBPUSD']
result = [{'pair' : pair['name'],
           'short' : pair['shortPercentage'],
           'long' : pair['longPercentage']}
          for pair in data if pair['name'] in interested]
print(result)
```

Output is shotred list:

```
[{'pair': 'EURUSD', 'short': 32, 'long': 68}, {'pair': 'GBPUSD', 'short': 54, 'long': 46}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

data = [{'name': 'EURUSD', 'shortPercentage': 32, 'longPercentage': 68, 'shortVolume': 22685.66, 'longVolume': 47762.79, 'longPositions': 89968, 'shortPositions': 56612, 'totalPositions': 146580, 'avgShortPrice': 1.1678, 'avgLongPrice': 1.199}, {'name': 'GBPUSD', 'shortPercentage': 54, 'longPercentage': 46, 'shortVolume': 6462.95, 'longVolume': 5587.2, 'longPositions': 17783, 'shortPositions': 22240, 'totalPositions': 40023, 'avgShortPrice': 1.3592, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3929}, {'name': 'USDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 89, 'longPercentage': 11, 'shortVolume': 32447.66, 'longVolume': 4081.71, 'longPositions': 10941, 'shortPositions': 58722, 'totalPositions': 69663, 'avgShortPrice': 106.7526, 'avgLongPrice': 108.6437}, {'name': 'GBPJPY', 'shortPercentage': 79, 'longPercentage': 21, 'shortVolume': 2725.22, 'longVolume': 711.99, 'longPositions': 3210, 'shortPositions': 9743, 'totalPositions': 12953, 'avgShortPrice': 146.1479, 'avgLongPrice': 149.2243}, {'name': 'USDCAD', 'shortPercentage': 47, 'longPercentage': 53, 'shortVolume': 6235.58, 'longVolume': 6930.97, 'longPositions': 16121, 'shortPositions': 13276, 'totalPositions': 29397, 'avgShortPrice': 1.2658, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3025}, {'name': 'EURAUD', 'shortPercentage': 32, 'longPercentage': 68, 'shortVolume': 562.13, 'longVolume': 1170.82, 'longPositions': 4444, 'shortPositions': 3004, 'totalPositions': 7448, 'avgShortPrice': 1.5434, 'avgLongPrice': 1.5816}, {'name': 'EURJPY', 'shortPercentage': 74, 'longPercentage': 26, 'shortVolume': 10500.41, 'longVolume': 3672.26, 'longPositions': 8166, 'shortPositions': 25254, 'totalPositions': 33420, 'avgShortPrice': 126.1881, 'avgLongPrice': 128.6925}, {'name': 'AUDCAD', 'shortPercentage': 48, 'longPercentage': 52, 'shortVolume': 1559.83, 'longVolume': 1699.36, 'longPositions': 5943, 'shortPositions': 6278, 'totalPositions': 12221, 'avgShortPrice': 0.9561, 'avgLongPrice': 0.979}, {'name': 'AUDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 83, 'longPercentage': 17, 'shortVolume': 1614.66, 'longVolume': 322.98, 'longPositions': 1905, 'shortPositions': 6048, 'totalPositions': 7953, 'avgShortPrice': 78.9751, 'avgLongPrice': 83.5306}, {'name': 'AUDNZD', 'shortPercentage': 63, 'longPercentage': 37, 'shortVolume': 673.48, 'longVolume': 403.95, 'longPositions': 2123, 'shortPositions': 3785, 'totalPositions': 5908, 'avgShortPrice': 1.0644, 'avgLongPrice': 1.0779}]

parsed = [[d["name"], d["shortPercentage"], d["longPercentage"]] for d in data]
print(tabulate(parsed, headers=["Name", "Short %", "Long %"], tablefmt="sql"))
```

Output:

```
Name      Short %    Long %
------  ---------  --------
EURUSD         32        68
GBPUSD         54        46
USDJPY         89        11
GBPJPY         79        21
USDCAD         47        53
EURAUD         32        68
EURJPY         74        26
AUDCAD         48        52
AUDJPY         83        17
AUDNZD         63        37
```

Comment: yes i am trying to get the output like this but as the json response keeps on changing not all of the response , just the numeric values keep on changing whenever there is a new response

Comment: Then use the new response if the values keep changing.

Answer (score 1):

From my assumption, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Result:

```
l=[{'name': 'EURUSD', 'shortPercentage': 32, 'longPercentage': 68, 'shortVolume': 22685.66, 'longVolume': 47762.79, 'longPositions': 89968, 'shortPositions': 56612, 'totalPositions': 146580, 'avgShortPrice': 1.1678, 'avgLongPrice': 1.199}, {'name': 'GBPUSD', 'shortPercentage': 54, 'longPercentage': 46, 'shortVolume': 6462.95, 'longVolume': 5587.2, 'longPositions': 17783, 'shortPositions': 22240, 'totalPositions': 40023, 'avgShortPrice': 1.3592, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3929}, {'name': 'USDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 89, 'longPercentage': 11, 'shortVolume': 32447.66, 'longVolume': 4081.71, 'longPositions': 10941, 'shortPositions': 58722, 'totalPositions': 69663, 'avgShortPrice': 106.7526, 'avgLongPrice': 108.6437}, {'name': 'GBPJPY', 'shortPercentage': 79, 'longPercentage': 21, 'shortVolume': 2725.22, 'longVolume': 711.99, 'longPositions': 3210, 'shortPositions': 9743, 'totalPositions': 12953, 'avgShortPrice': 146.1479, 'avgLongPrice': 149.2243}, {'name': 'USDCAD', 'shortPercentage': 47, 'longPercentage': 53, 'shortVolume': 6235.58, 'longVolume': 6930.97, 'longPositions': 16121, 'shortPositions': 13276, 'totalPositions': 29397, 'avgShortPrice': 1.2658, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3025}, {'name': 'EURAUD', 'shortPercentage': 32, 'longPercentage': 68, 'shortVolume': 562.13, 'longVolume': 1170.82, 'longPositions': 4444, 'shortPositions': 3004, 'totalPositions': 7448, 'avgShortPrice': 1.5434, 'avgLongPrice': 1.5816}, {'name': 'EURJPY', 'shortPercentage': 74, 'longPercentage': 26, 'shortVolume': 10500.41, 'longVolume': 3672.26, 'longPositions': 8166, 'shortPositions': 25254, 'totalPositions': 33420, 'avgShortPrice': 126.1881, 'avgLongPrice': 128.6925}, {'name': 'AUDCAD', 'shortPercentage': 48, 'longPercentage': 52, 'shortVolume': 1559.83, 'longVolume': 1699.36, 'longPositions': 5943, 'shortPositions': 6278, 'totalPositions': 12221, 'avgShortPrice': 0.9561, 'avgLongPrice': 0.979}, {'name': 'AUDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 83, 'longPercentage': 17, 'shortVolume': 1614.66, 'longVolume': 322.98, 'longPositions': 1905, 'shortPositions': 6048, 'totalPositions': 7953, 'avgShortPrice': 78.9751, 'avgLongPrice': 83.5306}, {'name': 'AUDNZD', 'shortPercentage': 63, 'longPercentage': 37, 'shortVolume': 673.48, 'longVolume': 403.95, 'longPositions': 2123, 'shortPositions': 3785, 'totalPositions': 5908, 'avgShortPrice': 1.0644, 'avgLongPrice': 1.0779}]

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i]["name"],end=" ")
    print(l[i]["shortPercentage"],end=" ")
    print(l[i]["longPercentage"],end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
EURUSD 32 68 

GBPUSD 54 46 

USDJPY 89 11 

GBPJPY 79 21 

USDCAD 47 53 

EURAUD 32 68 

EURJPY 74 26 

AUDCAD 48 52 

AUDJPY 83 17 

AUDNZD 63 37
```

If you want only some specific currencies, use conditional statements to only print those needed.

Comment: yes i am trying to get the output like this but as the json response keeps on changing not all of the response , just the numeric values keep on changing whenever there is a new response